# Как на время блокировать поток?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Отправляю пот запрос, в ходе работы приложения юзер может нажать снова на кнопку до того как предыдущий запрос не был окончен. Подскажите, как мне запрещать выполнять новый запрос, до того как не будет окончен предыдущий?

HTTP запрос отправляю так:

```
    public void onClick_Send(View view) throws MalformedURLException {

    if (!message_edit_text.getText().toString().equals("") /*&& public_key_my != null && private_key_my != null && who_open_key != null*/)
    {
        try {
            public_key_my = restorePublic();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        Log.d("TAG123", "Open key  my: " + public_key_my);
        final byte[] encrypt_by_from_key = encrypt(message_edit_text.getText().toString(), public_key_my);
        final byte[] encrypt_by_who_key = encrypt(message_edit_text.getText().toString(), public_key_who);
        //Log.d("TAG123", "Encrypted text: " + encryptedText);

        //if(encrypt_by_from_key != null && encrypt_by_who_key != null)
        {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("login", login)
                    .add("pass", password)
                    .add("encrypt_by_from_key", byte2Hex(encrypt_by_from_key))
                    .add("who_login", dialog_name)
                    .add("encrypt_by_who_key", byte2Hex(encrypt_by_who_key))
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://s92640jz.bget.ru/create_dialog.php")
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request)
                    .enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(final Call call, IOException e) {
                            // Error
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка при отправке запроса, проверьте подключение к сети", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.show();

                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                            String res = response.body().string();
                            Log.d("TAG", "All response is(onClick_Send): " + res);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    message_edit_text.setText("");
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    toast.show();
                                    Get_Messages(1);

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте условия `if(!onRequest)`, к примеру при отправке

```
onRequest = true
```

Когда получил

```
onRequest = false
```

Либо как посоветовали, блокируйте кнопку.

Comment: onRequest это булева переменная?

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, Очевидно, да.

Comment: ну да, а так, используйте хоть string (equals) или int (==), тут как будет удобнее.

Answer (score 2):

При отправке запроса блокируйте кнопку, при получении ответа – разблокируйте.